# Reason for vibration of guitar body while playing G string

Tags: guitar

While playing my guitar I noticed that the body of the guitar vibrates excessively, and I can feel it on my body while I play the open G string. Why is this? Is this because the natural frequency of the material of the body is same as that of the frequency of the G3 note?

Comment: Most likely, yes.